# how good is your relationship with them?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, ambiguity

> How many of your high school friends are you still in touch with and how good is your relationship with them?

Is the above sentence grammatical and meaningful?

Does **'them'** refer to 'your high school friends' or to '***those** of your high school* friends you are still in touch with'?

I think it is the latter although grammatically it seems to be the former. Common sense makes one realize that if one is not with touch with someone one can't have a relationship with them.

Answer (score 2):

The question of how pronouns get referred to noun phrases is a deep one in linguistics.  Certainly it isn't governed by any simple grammar rule, and you always have to consider the meaning of the nouns (as a simple example, we often use the perceived gender of the people in a situation to interpret gendered pronouns)

So please go with your common sense here.  "Them" must refer to the school friends that you are still in contact with.